# Django show data from RelatedManager in Model Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, foreign-key-relationship

This example below in admin if access Bar's page(add or edit) I can choose a register from Foo. However i want to when I access Foo's page (add or edit) show two field title and a list from Bar's elements registred from this Foo.

I've tried to use Manager Related, but I don't understand very well how it works.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

[image]